# How do I find the horizontal asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{\sin (x) }{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I can instantly see that there will be a vertical asymptote at $x=0$, however I am finding it quite a challenge to find a horizontal asymptote. I've drawn the graph and it seems as if the amplitude of this function decreases as we tend towards infinity, however that is the only remarkable thing I can say about it. Can someone help point out where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: sin(x) ~ x as x -> 0. There is no vertical asymptote at x=0.

Comment: There is no vertical asymptote at $x=0$, in fact $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @Eff How is this? $\sin (0)=0 \therefore \frac{\sin (0) }{0}$ should be indeterminate and there should be a vertical asymptote there right?

Comment: @seeker We are talking about the limit here. As $x$ approaches $0$, you are correct that $\sin x$ approaches zero, but so does the denominator. The closer to zero we get, the better the approximation $\sin x \approx x$ is, so when $x\approx 0$ we have that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\approx\frac{x}{x}=1$. This is not a very rigorous explanation, but just for your intuition. If $\sin x$ did not approach zero, but some nonzero number it would be correct that there would be a vertical asymptote.

Comment: There is a difference between "indeterminate" and "undefined". Any number divided by zero is undefined, but a certain category of those undefined numbers of the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ are called indeterminate.

In general, $\dfrac{t}{0}$ will approach $\infty$ if $t>0$ and $-\infty$ if $t<0$, but consider what happens when $t=0$.
$$s=\frac{t}{0}$$
is equivalent to
$$0s=t$$
Clearly, if $t=0$, $s$ does not have to approach $\pm\infty$ for this to be true. $s$ is called "indeterminate" because it cannot be uniquely determined algebraically (i.e. any Real number is a solution).

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

There is no vertical asymptote at $x = 0$. As for horizontal asymptotes,

$$\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{x}\right| \ \rightarrow 0 \ \hbox{ as } x \rightarrow \pm\infty$$

Comment: Why is there no vertical asymptote at $x = 0$?

Comment: As commented on above, the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin (x) /x$ exists and is equal to $1$.

Comment: How can this be when $\frac{\sin (0) }{0}$ is undefined?

Comment: @Seeker When looking at a limit, say $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ we do not look at the point $f(a)$. Instead we look at $f(x)$ as $x$ **approaches** $a$. Calculate, as an example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x=1$,$x=0.1$,$x=0.01$, etc. You can also try to graph the two functions $\sin x$ and $x$ and you will see that the graphs lie almost on top of each (are almost equal) when we are near $x=0$, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+vs+x).

Comment: @Eff, I see, thanks! So basically as we approach 0 the function tends to 1, however the function is undefined at the point $x=0$ and there is no vertical asymptote there.

Comment: @SimonS Could you provide a little exposition, where did this inequality come from?

Comment: For all $x$, $|\sin x| \leq 1$. Make sense?

Comment: @SimonS Ah I see. So y=0 is the horizontal asymptote? However I thought an asymptote was a line a function never crosses? This function seems to cross y=0 plenty..

Answer (score -1):

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-derivative-rules/ab-derivtive-rules-opt-vids/v/sinx-over-x-as-x-approaches-0
This link shows the proof that why when limit approaches 0,sinx/x equals to 1.