# The asymptote of $y=\mathrm{sinc}(t)$ as time increases

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, asymptotics

Is there any known approximate formula that maps decay percentage of $\mathrm{sinc}(t)$ with decaying time?

Or in other words, is there a known asymptote of $y=\mathrm{sinc}(t)$ as time increases?

Comment: Could you make the question more precise ?

Comment: You may use that $\mathrm{sinc}(x)=\sin(x)/x$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry about the double-edit, didn't mean to change the tags.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010537/how-do-i-find-the-horizontal-asymptote-of-fx-frac-sin-x-x

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\mathrm{sinc}(t) = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$ and $$\lim_{t \to +\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t} - 0= 0$$

So $y = 0$ is an asymptote of the function when $t \rightarrow +\infty$.